# updating the whole url in a database

Tags: php

http://in.linkedin.com/pub/nishit-mohan/5/382/a78

I am working on a php language and this is my first work in a cms .
I have made a cms for a website . Now the problem arise at that point when a user want to update the basic details  and in basic details  columns , there is a linkedin mail id . when the user click on the update button with the above id , It shows me this error :

**Not Acceptable**

**An appropriate representation of the requested resource /admin/update.php could not be found on this server.**

**Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**

but when I pass this **in.linkedin.com/pub/nishit-mohan/5/382/a78**   , it update the page without any problem . So I want to know what I am doing wrong and how to solve my problem .

I have inserted this **http://in.linkedin.com/pub/nishit-mohan/5/382/a78**

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't have the file /admin/update.php on your server. However the webserver is incapable of serving you with your own errordocument (404-page, 403-page, etc.) and shows you that message.

So do you have /admin/update.php located on your server? Or are you working in the wrong path perhaps?

Comment: but when i update in.linkedin.com/pub/nishit-mohan/5/382/a78 without http:// then it run the query and update without any problem but when i update with http://in.linkedin.com/pub/nishit-mohan/5/382/a78 , It shows me the above error

Comment: Ah, that makes the problem much more clear. Because of the standard escaping of Stackoverflow, I didn't fully grasp your question. However; do you escape your url before updating your database?

Comment: I am using mysql_real_escape_string to escape my url but its not working , is there any way to normalise the url